# Unable to download some packages on Redhat

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum, repository, subscription, rhel-7

I am unable to download the `pam-devel`, `zlib-devel` and `openssl-devel` packages on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo).

When executing `# yum install pam-devel` I am getting the following error:

```
error: No package pam-devel available.
error: Nothing to do
```

While running `# yum repolist all` the following content is being displayed:

[image: Output of repolist]

I am not able to enable the repositories running `# yum-config-manager --enable epel-source/x86_64`.

[image: Output]

Why are the packages not available and what I can do to get them?

Comment: Do you see any error when you run the enable?

Comment: @Seth no errors are shown.

Comment: Did you try to use quotes for the repo name? So `--enable "epl-source/x86_64"`? It shouldn't matter but it could?

Comment: same output @Seth

Comment: This might be better suited for the [Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).